# Microsoft Fakes Exception test case stopping solution at throw in catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

Solution is stopping at throw Exception in Catch block.

I have used below code

```cs
//TestMethod
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception), "Error occurred!")]    
public void Get_CatchException()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {

        IT.Common.Fakes.ShimSampleClass.AllInstances.GetString = (x, y) =>
        {
            throw new Exception("Error occurred!");
        };
        this._iSampleClass.Get(string);

    }
}

//Class method

public void Get(string Name)
{
    try
    {
        GetString(Name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex; 
    }
}
```

My requirement is Solution should not stop at throw and Exception test case should pass.

I am getting below error in class file and solution stopped.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to decipher your cryptic question. Can you explain a bit more? Tip: never use ` throw ex;`, use `throw;` instead.

Comment: Added screenshot FYR

Comment: Running All tests from Test-->Run-->All Tests ,instead of running/debugging particular exception test case, fixed the issue.

Comment: Debugging tests is something we might do if we wanted to break on the exception. Normally we just run them and we want to know if they pass or fail. But if it fails we might want to see what's going on in more detail, and then we might debug.

Comment: By default, when debugging, Visual Studio will stop at unhandled exceptions.